# Rails Devise won't write first_name and last_name to my DB's user table and keeps expecting an '@url.tld' at the end of each first and last name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, oauth, devise

I have implemented Devise in my Rails app and along with the Omniauth implementation, I have successfully made it so that people can create their own local account or can create an account through social authentication using their facebook acocunt.

However, I want to collect peoples' first and last names as well as their email address. I don't care for people to be able to log in with their first/last names, I just want to make it mandatory that I collect them on sign up, either in Devise's "Create Account" form or automatically through asking the Facebook API.

Here is my code so far:

**new.html.erb - devise/registrations**

This is the standard devise sign-up form that I have manually modified to include a link to my facebook signup link as well as manually added the first and last name sections. It is creating two problems: (1) For some reason it is requiring email-address like validations for first_name and last_name, requiring that each first and last name has an '@' symbol and then some copy.tld after it. (2) It ends up not even writing the contents of first_name and last_name to the db even after I add the '@fake.com' to the end of each name and the new user is written to the database. So I can go through the form and create a new user if I add '@fake.com' after first and last name, but those names don't even get written as part of the db row.

```
    <h3><%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook",                                                   user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %></h3>

    <h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :first_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :last_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

These are other related sections of my code that I have been desperately trying to amend to get any of this to work:

**Registrations Controller - controllers/users**

This is Devise's auto-generated Registrations Controller that I have amended with some code I found online to try to get this working. It doesn't seem to have worked:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

    def configure_devise_params
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
        u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
      end
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
        u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
      end
    end
```

**Registrations Controller - controllers**

This was a separate 'migrations controller' I generated at the behest of another tutorial I found online, again it seems to do nothing for me:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController


  private

    def sign_up_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    def account_update_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
    end

end
```

**Omniauth Callbacks Controller**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController


    def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)

    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    # if request.env["omniauth.auth"].info.email.blank?
    #   redirect_to "/users/auth/facebook?auth_type=rerequest&scope=email"
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user 
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
       redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end

  end
```

**Application Controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  #the point of this is so that when a person logs in who had never submitted an entry, he is taken to the New Entry page, if he has submitted he is taken to the Index page (root path) 
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource) 
      if current_user.entries.first
        root_path
      else
        entries_new_path
      end
  end


  private

  def configure_devise_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
      u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
  end

end
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

  #root url, specifically needed for Devise according to its instructions
  root to: 'entries#index'

  # devise_scope :user do
  #   get 'sign_out', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  # end

  #Entries routes
  get "/moderations" => 'moderations#index'
  get "/" => 'entries#index'
  get "/entries" => 'entries#index'

  get "/entries/new" => 'entries#new'
  get "/entries/:id" =>'entries#show'

  post "/entries" => 'entries#create'
  post "/votes" => 'votes#create'
  post "/moderations" => 'moderations#create'

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, right now is 2019 and I will give the answer to future person:

First, you need to go to `application_controller.rb` file and put these lines of codes into it:

```
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit({ roles: [] }, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :avatar) }
  end
```

Just write the parameters you wanna be listed. And in my case, these are first_name, last_name, and avatar.

For further research, you can read about the strong parameters on rails guide or you can watch a brief video right [here](http://www.lynda.com/Ruby-Rails-tutorials/Mass-assignment-strong-parameters/139989/159116-4.html)

The instructor explains it in a very easy-to-understand way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for a solution, but for any future Googlers:

I had this same problem, but figured it out myself. The problem is that the form lists the `first_name` and `last_name` fields as `email_field`:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :first_name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :last_name %>
</div>
```

They should be `text_fields`:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
</div>
```